# Scale expanded div to fill viewport using CSS for both orientation modes

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, fullscreen

I am developing for tablet and the objective is to have the expanded portion of a banner, expand to fullscreen on tablet. Since full-screen is not supported on mobile browsers I was hoping to find an alternative solution. Currently the div has a fixed width and height on it for both, portrait and landscape orientation.

Objective: Tablet: In portrait + landscape view to scale div to fill height preferably with CSS only or basic JS.

Not sure how to go about this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what your saying but have a look into media queries. They might be what you are looking for, it is pure css. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Hi, to clarify: I have built to a design that is set to the viewport of an iPad (768x1024) which is the targeted device. It's displaying the content perfectly fine based on the media-queries for portrait and landscape orientation, however since fullscreen is not supported on iOS Safari, how can I ensure that the content of the entire div is displayed without being cut off due to the browser window showing. Thanks!

Comment: @user2163224 please include your code or even better, create a jsfiddle so i can properly see your issue. Thanks